# how to setup AWS/mongodb with replicas so that if an instance crashes there is nothing to do?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

The question is pretty much all in the title : how to setup AWS/mongodb with replicas so that if an instance crashes there is nothing to do ?
Namely, if one of the instances of the replica crashes, I guess that Amazon instantiates a new machine for us and starts up the processes that were running. With EBS things should be fine.

Only problem : when restarting this, how can we add back the new machine to the replica set ?
Instances have changing ips and Im not sure how how start up the machine will know what replica set to join, what will be its ip, and how to tell to join it.
If you have encountered this problem please let me know !

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I guess that Amazon instantiates a new machine for us and starts up the processes that were running. With EBS things should be fine.

Downing of members can happen for many reasons on a network like AWS. I recommend strongly that you do not create an autoscaling group/cloud template for replicas.

Instead I would simply handle bringing up new replicas manually.

> With EBS things should be fine.

Not always, you could have an edge case whereby the storage layer for that dc also goes down. Infact it is normally more likely to be both than just one or the other.

> when restarting this, how can we add back the new machine to the replica set

As stated in the document on bringing members back up, this is mostly a manual process. You tell the `mongod` through the `--replicaSet` param what replica set it should be part of and then on the primary would need to remove that member from the rs.config and then reapply the new members IP.

You can, of course, assign static IPs to these instances and do it that way, AWS does support buying static IPs from them and they have an inteface for connecting them. This is quite elementary stuff so I won't go into it further.

Comment: Does AWS warn us of a machine going down ?
And in brief you suggest that this won't happen that often and we should do things manually instead of using some tools ?
Thanks

Comment: @Thomas You can get creatre an Alarm for that instance. If you right click on the EC2 instance in the control panel you will see an option for Alarms, you can code it to email you

Comment: @Thomas to add you wanna use the "status check failed" for system for Alarms

Comment: Thanks. What is the frequency of turn downs in your experience ?

Comment: @Thomas I think I have only ever had one failure on AWS so far and that was during hurricane sandy, I did used to get a few every month at the start but they have since gone